# What kind of noise is city noise?

Tags: noise, classification

White, pink, brown...? In general, to what category does it subscribe the spectrum of city noises, like traffic noise, ambulance/police siren, alarms, etc, put together?

If the question is too broad, then, what is the color for particular noises, like traffic?

Comment: The noise "colors" really refer to signals without distinguishable acoustic features, and describe very continuous power spectral densities (PSDs) that are assumed to be *stationary*. Sirens, for example, don't fit those categories at all - they are modulated tones by definition, and as such have a very time-dependent PSD. So, you can't apply your color categories to the individual kind of noise sources, but only to their sum, when there's enough different sources that the result, by pure randomness, becomes time-invariant in PSD again.  So, you're trying to apply inapplicable terms here :(

Comment: Maybe your question can be salvaged - for what *reason* or *purpose* are you asking this?

Comment: If there's more hills the motors generate more bass. You can get city noise samples from freesound and run  freq graphs from arbitrary lengths. You wount find that with 1000ds of sound sources and recording locations' that its a simple sound system thst has a known type. More walls or skyscrapers mdke different filters.

Answer (score 2):

Noise color isn't a rigorous model for traffic noise

https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/file/index/docid/506615/filename/Can_2010_Applied_acoustic_71_8_p.pdf